# Nginx rewrite rule not not passing variables if "/" is at the end of the url

Tags: php, regex, nginx

I am currently trying to create a Ngnix Rewrite rule that will pass variables back if a pattern is matched.

Request URL: `contoso.com/web/en-us/notifications/`

Nginx Rewrite rule`rewrite ^/web/(.*)/notifications/$ /web/?action=notifications&language=$1;`

So, with adding / at the end of notifications/, variable $_GET['action'] is empty. I do however get both values in $_GET['language'] = en-us/notifications

If i remove the / from the end of notifications, i get the correct values. in both variables.

How can i make this work even if the / is at the end?

Comment: And if you use `^/web/(.*)/notifications/?$`?

Comment: Same issue if i add question mark at the end.

Comment: Is there another `rewrite` rule in your configuration file that is matching the URI first?

Comment: @RichardSmith No other rule in config file that is matching :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. There was a rule on top that i did not initially caught that was setup for the home page that was causing the issue.

```
rewrite ^/web/(.*)/$ /web/?language=$1 last;
```

I moved this to the bottom under all other rewrite rules. fixed the issue.